# How to add the latest Jersey bundles to eclipse OSGI build

Tags: eclipse, build, jersey, osgi, tycho

I hope you gurus out there can help me with the following problem:

We implement an eclipse based RCP application using jersey for REST. We are defining our targetplatform such that no local bundles are allowed in any way (especially as our TYCHO based build is done by Jenkins running in a container, so it would be a problem to get the jars there). So to my understanding the bundles referenced by our targetplatform need to be available on a software site. We have no P2 support in our nexus (and wont get it), so installing them there is no option.

Now we want to use the latest Jersey version (being 2.29.1 I think) - but we found no update site which we can use. The latest jersey bundles available on orbit are extremely backlevel (2.22 I think).

I thought about wrapping the jersey JARs in an own plugin bundle, and re-exporting the packages, but AFAIK the jersey jars contain Activators, and they wouldn't run then ... so also this doesn't sound like an option.

So the question is: what is the recommended way to add the current jersey version to our targetplatform?

Thanks in advance for the help, 
 Chris

Comment: Is the problem that Jersey in the wanted version is no OSGi bundle(s), or that the Jersey OSGi bundles only exist as JARs but the build via Tycho requires a p2 update site?

Comment: The latter - they are OSGI bundles, but I dont know how to tell tycho where to pick them up. We configure tycho using the target-platform-configuration artifact, but a target platform may only refer to sites.

What's confusing me most: We are in the "eclipse world", and I find no update site hosting the current version of jersey .... this is totally unexpected, so I think I must be missing something very obvious here...

Comment: Either [create a p2 update site manually via Eclipse](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/project_wizards/new_update_site_project.htm) or [via Tycho (similar like here)](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/master/mirror-non-p2/pom.xml#L55).

Comment: And then I need to make this update site available on a webserver - right ? Or can Tycho use it directly from the File System?  

Sounds like a lot of effort to me just in order to resolve dependencies to some bundles - man I wish the whole eclipse / P2  build would get terminated and replaced with standard maven builds..... ;-(

Either way - thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: An update page is just a directory (similar to a local Maven repository). A (static) webserver is only required to make it public via HTTP/HTTPS. If you have OSGi bundle JARs, [put them into the subfolder `plugins` and simply create `artifacts.jar` and `content.jar` e.g. via Tycho](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/master/mirror-non-p2/pom.xml#L55). That's all. In contrast to OSGi, Maven can only resolves dependencies on build time, not on run time and does not provide enough metadata to resolve `Import-Package` dependencies.

Comment: So - without putting the update site onto a web server - how do I refer to it from my target definition? AFAIK relative paths cannot be used there, and a full path is a no-go as the build has to run on every machine ....

Comment: You can do the same as I did (see previous link): the first Maven Tycho build creates the update site and writes the path of the directory. The second Tycho build uses the update site.

Answer (score 0):

If your maven dependencies are already bundles you can simply allow tycho to use them to resolve requirements see https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform#.22POM_dependencies_consider.22

From Tycho 2.0 on it is also possible to download them, check into version control and reference them in the target platform via with a 'Directory' location entry

`<location path="${project_loc:name_of_your_target_project}/extra_bundles" type="Directory"/>`